# How I can make overlay on images of ul list but only on image not on full section of image?

Tags: html, css, image, sass, overlay

So I have a list of images. I want to make overlay on hover on image, I have it, but it works on full `<li></li>` element not on the image only, I want it to overlay only on image. Images have 1px gray border.
On the image, you can see that overlay have bigger size than image. (second image of the first row of images)

[image]

My html code:

```
<ul class="row portfolio-images-list justify-content-center justify-content-md-around justify-content-lg-around">
  <li class="portfolio-list-item col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <img class="img-border img-fluid" src="images/portfolio_first.png" alt="First Image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay-content">
        <h3 class="overlay-header">Project Title</h3>
        <a class="overlay-link" href="#">View Project</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="portfolio-list-item col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <img class="img-border img-fluid" src="images/portfolio_second.png" alt="Second Image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay-content">
        <h3 class="overlay-header">Project Title</h3>
        <a class="overlay-link" href="#">View Project</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="portfolio-list-item col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <img class="img-border img-fluid" src="images/portfolio_third.png" alt="Third Image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay-content">
        <h3 class="overlay-header">Project Title</h3>
        <a class="overlay-link" href="#">View Project</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="portfolio-list-item col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <img class="img-border img-fluid" src="images/portfolio_fourth.png" alt="Fourth Image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay-content">
        <h3 class="overlay-header">Project Title</h3>
        <a class="overlay-link" href="#">View Project</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="portfolio-list-item col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <img class="img-border img-fluid" src="images/portfolio_fifth.png" alt="Fifth Image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay-content">
        <h3 class="overlay-header">Project Title</h3>
        <a class="overlay-link" href="#">View Project</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="portfolio-list-item col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <img class="img-border img-fluid" src="images/portfolio_sixth.png" alt="Sixth Image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay-content">
        <h3 class="overlay-header">Project Title</h3>
        <a class="overlay-link" href="#">View Project</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My sass:

```
.portfolio-list-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;

  .img-border {
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ededed;
  }

  .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100%;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #34495e;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    transition: .5s ease;
  }

  &:hover .overlay {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }

  .overlay-content {
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created snippet for your describing issue. Lets check below snippet. Your `HTML` structure isn't correct for only `hover over` on `image`.

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before{
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
  width: 960px;
}
ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
li{
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 33.3333%;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 33.3333%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.card-image{
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}
.card-image img{
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.card-image .image-overlay{
  align-items: center;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.card-image .image-overlay h1{
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.card-image .image-overlay p{
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0;
}
.image-content{
  padding: 15px;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #121212;
}
.image-content h1{
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.image-content p{
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0;
}
li:hover .card-image .image-overlay{
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="card-image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="Card Image" />
        <div class="image-overlay">
          <h1>Card Image</h1>
          <p>Good Image</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="image-content">
        <h1>This is card content</h1>
        <p>This is description</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="card-image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="Card Image" />
        <div class="image-overlay">
          <h1>Card Image</h1>
          <p>Good Image</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="image-content">
        <h1>This is card content</h1>
        <p>This is description</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="card-image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="Card Image" />
        <div class="image-overlay">
          <h1>Card Image</h1>
          <p>Good Image</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="image-content">
        <h1>This is card content</h1>
        <p>This is description</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this help!!